# How many elliptic curves over a finite field have a square discriminant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

$\newcommand{\char}{\operatorname{char}}$Given a finite field $F_q$ with $q\equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $\char(F_q)>3$, I need to figure out how many isomorphism classes of elliptic curves $E/F_q$ have a square discriminant $\Delta:=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$.

Since $\char(F_q)>3$, we can consider short Weiestrass curves only ($y^2=x^3+ax+b$) where isomorphisms are given by $$(a,b)\mapsto (\lambda^4a, \lambda^6b),~\lambda\in F_q^*$$ and we can split isomorphism classes into four "superclasses" depending on whether $a=0$ and/or $b=0$.

**Superclass 1: $a=b=0$**

There are no elliptic curves here since it is singular.

**Superclass 2: $a=0,~b\neq0$**

The action of $F_q$ on the set of elliptic curves via $\lambda \ast b := \lambda^6 b$ has orbits of size $(q-1)/6$ (since both 2 and 3 divide $p-1$ by assumption). Since there are a total of $q-1$ curves here, this means there are 6 isomorphism classes in this superclass, and all of them have a square discriminant since $\Delta = -432b^2$ with $-432$ being a square since $q\equiv 1\bmod 3$.

**Superclass 3: $a\neq0,~b=0$**

By a similar argument on the orbits of $\lambda\ast a := \lambda^4 a$, if $q\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ then there are 2 isomorphism classes, whereas if $q\equiv 1\bmod 4$ then there are 4 isomorphism classes. Since $\Delta = -8^2a^3$, exactly half of the classes in either case have a square discriminant (this follows since all isomorphism classes have the same size and $a^3$ is a square half of the time).

**Superclass 4: $a,b\neq0$**

Each isomorphism class has size $(p-1)/2$ (the orbit size of $\lambda\ast(a,b):=(\lambda^4a,\lambda^6b)$), so it would suffice to find the raw number of solutions to $-16(4a^3+27b^2)=\delta^2$. Via a change of variables $(a',b',\delta')=(-a,\frac{3\sqrt{-3}}{4}b,\frac{\delta}{8})$, where $\sqrt{-3}$ exists since $q\equiv 1\bmod 3$, this can be simplified to
$$a^3+b^2=\delta^2,$$
so counting the number of points in this 2D surface (subject to $a,b\neq 0$) would conclude the task. I know there are some bounds for this, but I have been trying to get an exact solution to it without success.

Comment: In your last equation, let $a=A\delta$ and $b=B\delta$. Then you need to solve (ignoring $\delta=0$) the equation $$\delta A^3+B^2=1.$$ Now you can take any values for $A$ and $B$ in your field, and $\delta=\frac{1-B^2}{A^3}$. (Okay, not quite any value you need to discard $A=0$ and $B=\pm1$.